# Nesting a key value pair in a hash recursively in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to insert uuids in a deeply nested hash and I'm searching the way to do this in Ruby. Following code shows the function I use in PHP for this task:

```
function insert_uuids(&$array)
{
    if (!is_object($array) && !is_array($array)) {
        return;
    }

    if (is_object($array)) {
        $array->_uid = rand();
    }

    foreach ($array as &$subarray) {
        $this->insert_uuids($subarray);
    }
}

$this->insert_uuids($json);

// Gives me following result:
{
    "component": "root",
    "_uid": "3241242",
    "body": [
        {
            "component": "headline",
            "text": "42323",
            "_uid": "343214556"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Show the ruby code that you're trying to use.

Comment: My question is: How can I insert a key value pair recursively in a hash.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/onefriendaday/286daf85f038254529a6

Comment: Do not use a link to your code in a comment. Provide the minimum code and data necessary to demonstrate what you are trying to do in the question itself. Please read "[ask]".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

```rb
my_hash = {
    :title => "Home",
    :layout => "body--rimless",
    :content => {
        :sections => [
            {
                :component => "section",
                :style => "section--headed"
            }
        ]
    }
}

def insert_uuids(node)
  if node.is_a?(Hash)
    node[:_uid] = rand(100..9999)
    node.each do |k,v|
      if v.is_a?(Array)
        v.each do |elm|
          insert_uuids(elm)
        end
      elsif v.is_a?(Hash)
        insert_uuids(v)
      end
    end
  end
  return node
end

puts insert_uuids(my_hash)

# {:title=>"Home", :layout=>"body--rimless", :content=>{:sections=>[{:component=>"section", :style=>"section--headed", :_uid=>9639}], :_uid=>570}, :_uid=>4972}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Ruby example in the gist has some issues:

- The `json` variable is neither a JSON string nor a valid Ruby `Hash`
- There is no need to use empty brackets if there are not parameters
- There is no need to check for `is_a?(Hash)` or `is_a?(Array)`, because the `insert_uuids` method is only defined on `Hash`

I would start with something like this:

```
json = '{ "component": "root", "body": [{ "component": "headline", "text": "42323" }] }'

class Hash
  def insert_uuids
    subarrays = values.select { |value| value.is_a?(Array) }
    subarrays.each do |array|
      array.each do |element|
        element.insert_uuids if element.respond_to?(:insert_uuids)
      end
    end

    update('_uid' => 'some random uid')
  end
end

require 'json'
hash = JSON.parse(json)
hash.insert_uuids
#=> {"component"=>"root", "body"=>[{"component"=>"headline", "text"=>"42323", "_uid"=>"some random uid"}], "_uid"=>"some random uid"}
```

Comment: If you have nested hashes and inside a array it will not insert uids to the nested elements. See my updated answer.